# Finding basis of the subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

While finding the basis of a subspace in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is there a condition for the number of vectors or number of elements in the vectors? 
To be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, do you at least need $n$ number of vectors?

Comment: I worry you are overusing the word element and confusing yourself between the uses.  Any basis for any subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ will necessarily contain vectors from $\Bbb R^n$... i.e. each specific basis vector will be an $n$-tuple of real numbers, this because to be a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$, it must first be a sub*set* of $\Bbb R^n$ which further has other special properties.  A subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ may have any number of basis vectors from zero to $n$, and may not have strictly more than $n$ basis vectors (*else they could not be linearly independent and thus not a basis*).

Answer (score 2):

It's the opposite: a basis of a subspace $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has *at most* $n$ vectors (and it has exactly $n$ vectors when and only when $V=\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: Thanks! What about the second part of the question?

Comment: Which second part? What I wrote was meant to be a complete answer.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> To be a subspace of R^n, do you at least need n number of vectors?

No. Take our familiar $\mathbb{R}^3$. A line (through the origin) is a one dimensional subspace. So you can span it by one suitable vector. Similar a plane (through the origin) by two suitable vectors.